# Clicking the Image view inside the Child list of Expandable list

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an **expandable list** view which has an **imageview** and a **textview**. I can click on child view and do something but i want to click seperate imageview and textview in child of the expandable list and do different things for each. I want to do this in **main** not in the expandable adapter class.

```
final ExpandableListView exlv = this.getExpandableListView();

exlv.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, int arg3, long arg4) {


        Toast.makeText(ExpList.this,
                "Child ItemClicked " + arg2 + " " + arg3,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        imageView = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        Log.i("ImageView Value "," hi "+imageView.toString());
          imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override public void onClick(View arg0) { // TODO Auto-generated
              Log.v("clicked", "done");

         } });


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
});
```

I can click the image view after clicked the child with this code of course but i want to click the image view directly in the listview child. How could i do something like that or exlv.setOnImageViewClickListener ?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass BaseExpandableListAdapter, and in either:

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {}
```

or

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {}
```

Set your onClickListeners on your individually inflated views.

EDIT:

Sorry, I missed that you didn't want to do it in the adapter.  I know that listview has a method - setItemsCanFocus() that might be helpful.

Check out this google I/O - I found it really helpful:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

They talk about set item can focus around ~24:00